# missing watsapp contacts on new phone with same sim

Tags: contacts

i changed my sim from my old phone(nokia n8) to a new phone(samsung GT-S6310L)

on my new phone....i am not seeing few

numbers of my friends in the watsapp contact list.how can i get or restore their

numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Transfering the sim does NOT transfer the contacts as well.

You should try using bluetooth to transfer your contacts between the two phones, I believe NOKIA has a built in feature for that in their Symbian Models.

Answer (score 0):

Put your sim card back in your old phone. Navigate to the contact you wish to save, there should be an option somewhere to save the contact to your SIM card. Save all of the contacts, then put the sim card into your new device and you should be fine.